# eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker calendar is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I decided to use webpack in my project and refactor my legacy-styled code.
All other plugins (like: datatables, select2, etc.) work fine.

So I have a problem with eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker v4.17.47 where calendar is empty, but I can choose time. I googled but couldn't find similar issue.

I'm using jQuery v3.2.1, also tried with jquery 2.2.3. All the same.

[Calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbQ7N.png)

[Time image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u8Eu.png)

Here is my code:

```
// jquery.init.js
var $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;


// Article_create.js
var moment = require('moment');
moment.locale('fr');
window.moment = moment;

require('bootstrap');
require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');
// also tried with require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker-npm');
// and this require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min');

$('#article-datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    // locale: window.pageParameters.locale,
    // minDate: moment()
});
```

Have you had the same problem?

Comment: Just a question, have you included the css file ?

Comment: @pbenard  yes, i've included css

Comment: Ok, I think you should create a jsfiddle in order to reproduce your issue, it seems hard to help you just with pictures.... I never seen this kind of bug before...

Comment: @pbenard I've tried to use plugin in old-style with including script tags on page. And it isn't working with jQuery 3.2.1. However package.json of eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker says that it is compatible with jQuery ^3.0.

Comment: The problem is that I have jQuery 3.2.1 for frontend part and 2.2.3 for admin.

Comment: I found the reason of problem. I'm using AdminLTE for backend part. There was the file "datepicker/datepicker3.css".